# Factory boy yielding a "maximum recursion depth exceeded" error

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I'd like to defined two models, `Company` and `Package`. Each `Package` has only one `Company`, but a `Company` can have several `Packages`. However, each company can have only one `default_package` (which can be null). I've set this up as follows:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    default_package = models.OneToOneField(
        'dashboard.Package',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='default_for_%(class)s')


class Package(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

where `dashboard` is the app label.

In order to simplify tests with these models, I've created test factories for them using [`factory_boy`](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as follows:

```
import factory
from .models import Company, Package

class CompanyFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Company 

    default_package = factory.SubFactory('dashboard.test_factories.PackageFactory')


class PackageFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Package

    company = factory.SubFactory(CompanyFactory)
```

Now I'm trying two tests:

```
class DefaultPackageTest(TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        company = Company.objects.create()

    def test_2(self):
        company = CompanyFactory()
```

The first one simply creates a `Company`, whereas the second one tries to do the same thing using the `CompanyFactory`.

Strangely, however, the first test passes, whereas the second one fails:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 233, in recurse
    return builder.build(parent_step=self, force_sequence=force_sequence)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 272, in build
    step.resolve(pre)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 221, in resolve
    self.attributes[field_name] = getattr(self.stub, field_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 355, in __getattr__
    declaration = self.__declarations[name]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/factory/builder.py", line 121, in __getitem__
    context=self.contexts[key],
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.012s

FAILED (errors=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Any idea why this is not working? I believe I have followed the docs (http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#circular-imports) by providing a full path to the `CompanyFactory`'s sub-factory.

**Update**

It seems that this use case is addressed by Factory Boy's [post-generation hooks](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#post-generation-hooks). What seems promising is the [`RelatedFactory`](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#relatedfactory), for which the following example is given:

```
class CityFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = City

    capital_of = None
    name = "Toronto"

class CountryFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Country

    lang = 'fr'
    capital_city = factory.RelatedFactory(CityFactory, 'capital_of', name="Paris")
```

which is tested in the Python REPL as follows:

```
>>> france = CountryFactory()
>>> City.objects.get(capital_of=france)
<City: Paris>
```

I'm having difficulty, however, applying this example to my situation. (It doesn't help that there is no text explanation or code of the `City` and `Country` models in the docs). It seems like `capital_city` is analogous to `default_package` in my case, so I tried turning it into a `RelatedFactory` like so,

```
default_package = factory.RelatedFactory('dashboard.test_factories.PackageFactory')
```

but I still get the same error.

Comment: I think you followed the first part of the docs, regarding circular imports, but not the final piece of advice. What if you create the company with `company = CompanyFactory(default_package=None)` and then `CompanyFactory(default_package__company=company)`?

Comment: I've noticed that if I try this, the instance of `Company` thus created does not have a `default_package` attribute. What I would actually like to do is when I create a company with the `CompanyFactory`, also create a `Package` object whose `default_for_company` is that company. How might I achieve this?

Comment: I don't have factory_boy here to test, but now that you have the `company`, can't you create a package with that company and then set the `company`'s `default_package` to that package?

Answer (score 4):

So, I achieved that by implementing a `post_generation` function:

```
    class PackageFactory(factory.Factory):
        class Meta:
            model = Package

        company = factory.SubFactory('dashboard.test_factories.CompanyFactory')

    class CompanyFactory(factory.Factory):
        class Meta:
            model = Company 

        @factory.post_generation
        def default_package(self, create, _, **__):
            PackageFactory(company=self)
```

The `company=self` kwarg stops the recursion and the factory is properly created with the desired default package attribute.